# Failed to install Nvidia drivers390.48 for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, dkms

I'm installing nvidia driver version=390.48 at tty.
I shutdown lightdm and get nouveau into blacklist before installation.
And I got a error when installing DKMS kernel module

> ERROR: Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 390.48 -k 4.13.16-041316-generic`:

Installation failed and I could not login my ubuntu in GUI mode.
Ubuntu=16.04, Linux kernel=4.13.16
My /var/log/nvidia-installer.log is listed blow.

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Thu May  3 11:17:06 2018
installer version: 390.48

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 390.48.
-> There appears to already be a driver installed on your system (version: 390.48).  As part of installing this driver (version: 390.48), the existing driver will be uninstalled.  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
-> Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later. (Answer: Yes)
-> Installing both new and classic TLS OpenGL libraries.
-> Installing both new and classic TLS 32bit OpenGL libraries.
-> Install NVIDIA's 32-bit compatibility libraries? (Answer: Yes)
-> Will install GLVND GLX client libraries.
-> Will install GLVND EGL client libraries.
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so.390.48"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so.1"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so.390.48"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so.1"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "./32/libGL.so.390.48"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so.1"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "./32/libEGL.so.390.48"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so.1"
-> Parsing log file:
-> done.
-> Validating previous installation:
-> done.
-> Uninstalling NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 (1.0-39048 (390.48)):
-> DKMS module detected; removing...
-> done.
-> Uninstallation of existing driver: NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 (390.48) is complete.
Looking for install checker script at ./libglvnd_install_checker/check-libglvnd-install.sh
   executing: '/bin/sh ./libglvnd_install_checker/check-libglvnd-install.sh'...
   Checking for libglvnd installation.
   Checking libGLdispatch...
   Can't load library libGLdispatch.so.0: libGLdispatch.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Will install libglvnd libraries.
Will install libEGL vendor library config file to /usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d
-> Searching for conflicting files:
-> done.
-> Installing 'NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64' (390.48):
   executing: '/sbin/ldconfig'...
-> done.
-> Driver file installation is complete.
-> Installing DKMS kernel module:
ERROR: Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 390.48 -k 4.13.16-041316-generic`: 
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' -j8 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.13.16-041316-generic modules....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for nvidia: 390.48 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.16-041316-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.48/build/make.log for more information.
-> error.
ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS. No kernel module was installed; please try installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS logs for more information.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest you try installing the latest NVIDIA driver version.

To do this, you would add the graphics driver PPA with the following commands in terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

After this, you should now remove any current NVIDIA drivers by entering the following into your terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

Now that you have done this, it is safe to install the latest version:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-396`

Please note that it is nvidia-driver-396 on Ubuntu 18.04, it is nvidia-396 on Ubuntu 16.04 but you are not using 16.04.

Comment: WARNING: Installing nvidia drivers through apt is not recommended, and it's usually better to install through nvidia installer binaries.

Comment: Do you have a source or any context for that? Installing via apt provides dkms support which allows your NVIDIA drivers to easily survive kernel updates by being re-built automatically, and it also automatically installs NVIDIA driver updates for your specific driver branch. I've been using apt for NVIDIA drivers for over 4 years without any issues.